# installation on RAID set "seeking device"

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, raid

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 (No 13.10 because of this error (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1241589)), the installation succeeded, but with an error that he could not install bootloader (GRUB). Okay, i downloaded boot-repair and this one sad that it was successfully installed. But now, when i restart, it hangs on purple/yellow screen (GRUB). When i click on Advanced options (after a reboot in the GRUB screen) and start Ubuntu (not recovery), then I'll see some errors `seeking device "/dev/dm-1" to ....` etc.

My boot-repair summery: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6322420/

I've installed Ubuntu before, also on the RAID set, but i haven't had this error yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround, ext3 instead of ext4.. It wasnt the seeking device error, but it hangs on boot on something with `ext4-fs remounted`. Ex3 fixed the issue... If someone can explain how/why, would it be nice.